# efficient thread mechanism to use for a permanently running process

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have a process that I need to run almost permanently. I've being using performSelectorInBackground to achieve this. Using this code my application is suffering greatly performance wise manifesting itself in glitchy audio. Using a profiler on the code below it uses up 50% of all the time being run.

I want to know if this is the best thread mechanism to use for a permanently running background process?

Do other thread types such as gcd async dispatch run quicker than my example or are all thread types executed at the same speed with the same amount of resources?

Is there a way to reduce the amount of resources allocated to a thread process?

```
   [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(myProgressTask) withObject:nil];

    - (void)myProgressTask {        

        while (doprocess==YES) 
       {
            //execute stuff

       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use NSRunLoop in your thread. [Add timer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSRunLoop/addTimer%3aforMode%3a) and execute stuff in an appropriate callback. You can stop that loop by invalidating timer. You can also play with thread priority and choose one that fits your needs the best. Aldo check docs for NSThread and NSOperation.

Comment: to clarify.... are you suggesting that I execute a NSRunLoop inside my performSelectorInBackground method or replace the performSelectorInBackround with a NSRunLoop?

Comment: Use it in performSelectorInBackground  method. This will create the new runloop on a separate thread (Cocoa creates the one on the main thread for you implicitly).

Answer (score 1):

Spawning a thread is always expensive, no matter what technique you are using (pthread, NSThread (which is just a high level wrapper for pthread), gcd (which is also pthread with a different color, etc).

Here is a pretty good article which compares the resources/time needed to spawn a thread and do some operation: http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/overhead-of-spawning-threads.html

However, as you say that the thread has performance impacts on your main thread, you can do two things: Lower the priority of your thread which will let the OS know that the thread needs less CPU cycles, or returning the not needed CPU time back to the system. The other way is using the NSRunLoop/CFRunLoop mechanism to do the operation, however, this only works if its a small but repeating operation (looks so from your code snippet). Performing heavy code in the run loop might not be the best idea, but its non-blocking to some degree (until you block the runloop with your code) and you don't have the overhead of spawning a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

Before providing you with a technical answer, I would suggest that you revisit the overall design of your application. Having a thread running all of the time is usually wrong. At least, you should try to execute periodically a function/callback.

Having said that, you can use the low-level pthreads library to reduce the amount of resources allocated to your thread. None of the high-level mechanisms that I am aware of provide this detail of configuration. With pthreads (and with any other mechanism you use) it's important to relinquish the CPU from time to time so that other threads can actually access it. This is why at the moment you are experiencing a performance problem. Probably, the other threads in your apps are simply starving. To avoid this, even without using pthreads, you may call both `usleep()` and `sched_yeld()` where appropriate in your code to periodically relinquish the CPU. The other threads now have a chance to execute.

if you decide to switch to pthreads, then before spawning your thread with `pthread_create()`, you may want to set its attributes in order to limit the resources assigned to it using `pthread_attr_setschedparam(`), `pthread_attr_setschedpolicy()` and `pthread_attr_setscope()`.